# PySpark - if when condition is not satisfied do nothing

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, conditional-statements

I have a when/otherwise statement as follows:

`df_3 = df_2.withColumn('date', when(size('date') == 1, col('date')[0]).otherwise(col('date'))).withColumn('price', when(size('price') == 1, col('price')[0]).otherwise(col('price')))`

This gives me an error `data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type`.

What I have is a `date` column and `price` column, both of which contains arrays. If there is only one element in the array, I want to simply have that as a string, otherwise (if there is more than 1 element) leave it how it is. So my `when` and `otherwise` would never match type -- one would be a string and the other would be an array.

Is there a way to fix this?

Input:

```
+-------------+-----------+
|         date|      price|
+-------------+-----------+
|           []|         []|
|[25-Mar-2020]|   [95, 95]|
|           []|         []|
|           []|         []|
|           []|         []|
+-------------+-----------+
```

Output (getting rid of empty array would also help but not that big of a deal):

```
+-------------+-----------+
|         date|      price|
+-------------+-----------+
|           []|         []|
|  25-Mar-2020|   [95, 95]|
|           []|         []|
|           []|         []|
|           []|         []|
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: For clarity, could you add an example of your dataframe? Ideally something other can copy and paste.

Comment: added in sample input/output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "mix" the types in the column. Each column in a PySpark DataFrame has its schema defined. What you're trying to do is input both Integer and Array types on a column that has ArrayType on Schema. My suggestion is try to convert the values to String instead:

```py
df_3 = (
   df_2
     .withColumn('date', 
            when(size('date') == 1, col('date')[0])
           .otherwise(concat_ws(",", col('date'))))
)
```